# How I can show a webview in a tabwidget?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, webview

How I can show a webview in a tabwidget?
When I open the tab, the webview opens in other new page without opens in a tabcontent.
Where is the problem?

code activity.class :

> public class layout1i2 extends Activity{
>   Button button1, button2;
>   WebView webview1, webview2;
>
> ```
>       @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
>     setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
>
>           //declarar webvies i botó de tirar enrere       webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);       button1 = (Button)
> ```
>
> findViewById(R.id.button1);       button2 = (Button)
>   findViewById(R.id.button2);
>                 webview1.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");        webview1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
>
> ```
>           button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()        {           @Override           public void onClick(View arg0)              {
>           setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
>           webview2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
>           button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
>           button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
>           {
>               @Override
>               public void onClick(View arg0) 
>               {
>                   setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
>                   webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);       
>               }
>           });             }
> ```

```
});
```

}

layout2.xml

> ```
>       <RelativeLayout
>           android:id="@+id/Layout2"
>           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
>
>           <WebView
>               android:id="@+id/webview2"
>               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>               android:autoLink="web"
>               android:scrollbars="none"
>               android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
>
>           <Button
>               android:id="@+id/button2"
>               style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>               android:layout_width="60dp"
>               android:layout_height="25dp"
>               android:layout_below="@+id/webview2"
>               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>               android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
>               android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
>               android:text="Button2"
>               android:textSize="14px" />
>
>       </RelativeLayout>
> ```

layout1.xml

> ```
>       <RelativeLayout
>           android:id="@+id/Layout1"
>           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
>
>           <WebView
>               android:id="@+id/webview1"
>               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>               android:autoLink="web"
>               android:scrollbars="none"
>               android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
>
>           <Button
>               android:id="@+id/button1"
>               style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>               android:layout_width="60dp"
>               android:layout_height="25dp"
>               android:layout_below="@+id/webview2"
>               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>               android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
>               android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
>               android:text="Button1"
>               android:textSize="14px" />
>
>       </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Thank's. My problem was this. jajaja I forgot write this line. Thank's!